# How to convert string year-month into complete date in format 2018-12-01 in Pentaho Data Integrity CE

Tags: date-formatting, pentaho-data-integration

I am getting month and year in string format (2018-December) in excel file and I want to convert it into date format 2018-12-01 (day can be always 01) and write all data in PostgreSQL Database with Pentaho Data Integrations CE.

I tried to do it with select values, tab "Meta-data", Format -> yyyy-MMMM, but I got an error "couldn't convert string [2018-July] to a date using format [yyyy-MMMM]". 
[pentaho transformation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqaIR.jpg)

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to convert Text data (name of the month) to Date, that won't work, you'll have to treat this data first before converting to Date type.

Since your data is coming with a separator, you can treat the second part with Value Mapper, or a Replace in string step.

[image]

After that you can concatenete the string back with a separator and then use the Select Values.

Comment: Thank you Cristian. But there is no day in the date? Will it work only with year and month?

Comment: You can also build a date with both values with the formula Step, use the following formula DATE([year];[month];1), and in the formula step use Type Date, this will create a DATE type column with the Year and Month you extratcted, and always day 1.